# Simple Ruby pop not working

Tags: arrays, ruby, stack

This is supposed to reverse a string. I'm not sure why my iterator `i` stops at 10. Here is the code -

```
def word_reverser_pop(sent)
   arr = Array.new()
   arr = sent.split("")
   reverse = Array.new(arr.length)
   i = 0
   p arr.length
   while i < arr.length 
       reverse.unshift(arr.pop)
       i += 1
   end
   return reverse
end

p word_reverser_pop("This is another test")
```

Output:

```
20

["o", "t", "h", "e", "r", " ", "t", "e", "s", "t", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: More Ruby-like would be: `"happy".each_char.with_object([]) { |c,a| a.unshift(c) }.join #=> "yppah" `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#pop` removes an object from an array. This also means that the length of it decreases by 1. Assign it to a variable before the `while`-loop and use that new variable instead of calling `Array#length` every iteration.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! My corrected code - `code` def word_reverser_pop(sent)
 arr=Array.new()
 arr = sent.split("")
 reverse = Array.new(arr.length)
 i = 0
 len = arr.length 
 while i < len 
  reverse.push(arr.pop)
  i += 1
 end
 return reverse.join("")
end  `code`